# sort array with inner array

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I want to sort an array with JavaScript so that the array is sorted from small to large based on numbers.
How can I do this?

```
var data=[['5','09:01:00','5003','153980',0],
['8','09:01:00','4500','153980',0],
['2','09:01:00','4000','153980',0],
['1','09:01:00','3884','153980',0],
['3','09:01:00','2000','153980',0],
['6','09:01:00','1647','153980',0],
['7','09:01:00','1000','153980',0],
['4','09:01:00','1000','153980',0],
['9','09:01:00','800','153980',0],
['10','09:01:00','700','153980',0],
['11','09:01:00','587','153980',0],
['12','09:01:00','554','153980',0],
['99','09:01:00','390','153980',0],
['998','09:01:00','333','153980',0],
['15','09:01:00','300','153980',0],
['16','09:01:00','300','153980',0],
['100','09:01:00','229','153980',0],
['120','09:01:00','205','153980',0],
['241','09:01:00','70','153980',0],
['25','09:01:00','65','153980',0],
['206','09:01:00','62','153980',0],
['207','09:01:00','57','153980',0],
['28','09:01:00','50','153980',0],
['1029','09:01:00','50','153980',0],
['300','09:01:00','40','153980',0],
['3001','09:01:00','37','153980',0],
['30232','09:01:00','35','153980',0],
]
```

like this:

```
data =[[1,...],[2,...],[3,...],[4,...],[5,...],...
```

Comment: just pick the value for sorting and use [`Array#sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use the `.sort()` method and pass it a comparator function:

```
data.sort( function(a, b) {
  // Extract the numbers to compare:
  let n1 = parseInt( a[0] );
  let n2 = parseInt( b[0] );

  // If they are equal:
  if ( n1 == n2 ) {
    return 0;
  }

  return ( n1 < n2 ? -1 : 1 );
} );
```